# Anchor tag Click To Call is not working in latest browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-os

I have developed Click To Call functionality before a year, and was working in all browsers.
But now we have upgraded our chrome browser version from 111 to 113, and click to call is not working for Chrome.

When I open a page, Click To Email is working, but Click To Call is not working in Chrome browser. Though it's working in other browsers (Firefox and IE).

From Google I see below page, which having similar issue (Click To Call not working for Chrome)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Question is, How can I make it working in latest Chrome Browser?

Below is my sample HTML code

```
<a href="tel:+9052355">Phone 1</a>
<a href="tel:9052355">Phone 2</a>
```

Above links are working in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Comment: Please share your code!

Comment: updated question with sample HTML code

Comment: working fine chrome browser with 113  https://jsfiddle.net/2ecohkd9/

Comment: Do we have any settings in browser? given fiddle example is not working for me, my Chrome version is, 113.0.5672.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: same here, it doesn't work in chrome 113.0.5672.127 official 64 bit